# Google Maps, open info window after click on a link

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have this code to display a google map:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.714364, -74.005972),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlemap"), mapOptions);


        var locations = [
            ['New York', 40.714364, -74.005972, 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png']
        ];


        var marker, i;
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.close();
        });


        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map,
                icon: locations[i][3]
            });


            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }

    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<div id="googlemap" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
<a href="#">Open Info Window</a>
```

That's not the final code, because i want add more markers.

The problem is, that i need external links to open the info window of a marker.


For Example:

Link 1 opens the info window from marker 1
Link 2 opens the info window from marker 2
etc...

I need a link something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:marker(0)">Open Info Window One</a>
```

Here is my code in jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fJ4jG/3/

I found couple of solutions, but i don't know how to use this code together with my code.
It should work like this:
http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map2.html

Thanks for every help!

Comment: Why haven't you tried that than?

Comment: I have tried it several times, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

What that example does is it creates an array where it stores the markers. So when the markers are created, they get pushed to that markers array. When you click on the link you send an index with the function that is a reference to the marker in the array.

So JavaScript looks like this:

```
var markers = [];
// The array where to store the markers

function initialize() {

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.714364, -74.005972),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlemap"), mapOptions);


        var locations = [
            ['New York', 40.714364, -74.005972, 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png']
        ];


        var marker, i;
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.close();
        });


        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map,
                icon: locations[i][3]
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));

            // Push the marker to the 'markers' array
            markers.push(marker);
        }

    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    // The function to trigger the marker click, 'id' is the reference index to the 'markers' array.
    function myClick(id){
        google.maps.event.trigger(markers[id], 'click');
    }
```

And in your HTML `a` tag you add the `myClick` function like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myClick(0);">Open Info Window</a>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fJ4jG/9/

Comment: Thank you!!! I used your code, because of the extra "myClick" function - that's exactly what i need.

Comment: How do I modify my code (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22455705/how-to-open-a-infowindow-of-a-marker-in-google-maps-from-a-link) to work with your working solution? Thanks.

Comment: Excellent answer! Perfect solution for my needs!

Comment: Can you explain why should we pass marker and i to a new function and return a function again? Why a simple function not working on the variable "marker"?

Answer (score 11):

As in my example.

1. add a global array to save references to the google.maps.Marker objects:

   ```
   var gmarkers = [];
   ```
2. push the markers onto that array as you create them

   ```
   gmarkers.push(marker);
   ```
3. trigger the "click" event on the desired marker:

   ```
   <a href="javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[0],'click');">Open Info Window</a>
   ```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9vnpP/2/)

Answer (score 0):

use this code i already tried it

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

                   infoWindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                   infoWindow.open(map, marker);


      });
```

Comment: Can you please send me the jsfiddle? It doesen't work for me.

Comment: Don't understand how this should work with this code. Did you perhaps read question wrong?

Comment: declare your var map outside initialize() then use this  `map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlemap"), mapOptions);` insted of `var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlemap"), mapOptions);` after that you can play with your map using javascript `onclick()` call a function in that show begins or another alter native method can be  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469322/google-maps-api-showing-a-markers-infowindow-from-a-link-outside-of-the-map]