# JS Gmaps API, How to serialize data from a href values for open and center markers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

How to serialize data from a href values?

I created a code based on two examples in Stack, the mixture of the two gets:

- By clicking on a href pan to new position
- Generate markers with loop "for"

I would understand how I can serialize a href values to automatically generate the markers to avoid writing twice geolocation code.

Any ideas? thanks

```
<html>
<a name="locations"></a>
<ul>
    <li><a class="location_class" data-location_phi="41.3947901,2.1487679">Barcelona</a></li>
    <li><a class="location_class" data-location_phi="41.1258048,1.2385834">Tarragona</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="testmap"></div>
</html>

<script>
var locations = [
  ['loan 1', 41.3947901,2.1487679, 'address 1', 'some1'],
  ['loan 2', 41.1258048,1.2385834, 'address 2', 'some2']
  ];

function pan_func(latlon) {
    var coords = latlon.split(",");
    var panPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]);
    map.panTo(panPoint);
}

function setMarkers(map,locations){
    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

        var loan = locations[i][0];
        var lat = locations[i][1];
        var longi = locations[i][2];
        var add =  locations[i][3];
        var add_phi =  locations[i][4];
        var latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, longi);

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
            map: map,
            title: loan,
            position: latlngset
        });
        var content = "<h3>Loan Number: " + loan +  '</h3>' + "Address: " + add + add_phi; 
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', phi_test(marker,content,infowindow)); 

    }

    function phi_test (marker,content,infowindow){ 
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
            map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
         };
     }
}

var map;

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.3947901,2.1487679),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('testmap'), mapOptions);

    $('.location_class').on('click', function () {
        pan_func($(this).data('location_phi'));
    });
    setMarkers(map,locations);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/thetipico/9Lemwp07/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done!

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="myClick(0);">Barcelona</a><br>
<a href="#" onclick="myClick(1);">Tarragona</a>
<div id="googlemap" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>

<script>
// SERIALIZE MARKERS
var markers = [];
    function initialize() {

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 10,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.3947901, 2.1487679),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlemap"), mapOptions);


            var locations = [
                ['Barcelona', 41.3947901, 2.1487679, 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png'],
                ['Tarragona', 41.1258048, 1.2385834, 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png']
            ];


            var marker, i;
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.close();
            });


            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                    map: map,
                    icon: locations[i][3]
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        // OPEN MARKERS
                        map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
                    };
                })(marker, i));

                markers.push(marker);
            }

        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        // CLEAN EVENT ACTION TO GET THE ID OF CURRENT MARKER AND TRIGGER POSTIION AND OPEN INFOWINDOW
        function myClick(id){
            google.maps.event.trigger(markers[id], 'click');
        }
</script>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/thetipico/h4bb1acz/3/)

Author Source: [Google Maps, open info window after click on a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333679/google-maps-open-info-window-after-click-on-a-link)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to store coordinates and address info in data-attributes, obtaining more flexible code in result: need one more marker? — just add another <a>!

```
<html>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="location_class" data-location_phi="41.3947901,2.1487679" data-loan="loan 1" data-add="address 1" data-add_phi="some1">Barcelona</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="location_class" data-location_phi="41.1258048,1.2385834" data-loan="loan 2" data-add="address 2" data-add_phi="some2">Tarragona</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="location_class" data-location_phi="46.4841143,30.7388449" data-loan="" data-add="address 3" data-add_phi="">Odessa</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="testmap"></div>
</html>
```

JS

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.3947901, 2.1487679),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    setMarkers(
        new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('testmap'), mapOptions)
    );
}

function setMarkers(map) {
    // Find links with "data-location_phi" attribute,
    // that contains coordinates required for marker placement
    var a = document.querySelectorAll('[data-location_phi]');
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        // Create an instance of MapMarker class for every location link
        new MapMarker(map, a[i]);
    }
}

function MapMarker(map, a) {
    this.a = a;
    this.map = map;
    this.dataset = {};
    this.fillDataSet();
    // Since we don't validate data in attributes it may cause some exceptions
    try {
        var loc = this.dataset.location_phi.split(',');
        this.latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(loc[0], loc[1]);
        this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: this.map,
            title: this.dataset.loan,
            position: this.latLng
        });
        // Bind event listeners
        this.bind();
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

MapMarker.prototype.fillDataSet = function () {
    var self = this;
    Array.prototype.slice.call(self.a.attributes).forEach(function (attr) {
        if (attr.name.substr(0, 5) == 'data-') {
            self.dataset[attr.name.substr(5)] = attr.value;
        }
    });
}

MapMarker.prototype.panTo = function () {
    this.map.panTo(this.latLng);
}

MapMarker.prototype.showInfo = function () {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var content = '<h3>Loan Number: ' + this.dataset.loan + '</h3>' +
                  'Address: ' + this.dataset.add + this.dataset.add_phi;
    infowindow.setContent(content);
    infowindow.open(this.map, this.marker);
}

MapMarker.prototype.bind = function () {
    var self = this;
    // Click on the link
    self.a.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        self.panTo();
    });
    // Click on the marker
    google.maps.event.addListener(
        self.marker,
        'click',
        function () {
            self.showInfo();
            self.panTo();
        }
    );
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9Lemwp07/9/)

Comment: Much better this solution, nice! Thank you!

Comment: one more question, how I can implement AutoOpen infowindow when I press the link?

Comment: How could you change the object's class to make different types of markers? I would understand how I can make the markers appear or disappear depending on their class in a link. I understand that I must add "data-markerclass = myvalue" to ahref and create the condition "MapMarker" object but not know how to raise it in the code. That is possible?

Comment: Not sure in understanding your question completely, but if you are looking for a way to customize some markers differently depending on their class names or something else, you can create CustomMapMarker class inheriting from MapMarker and add some whistles there. Check out the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9Lemwp07/13/).

Comment: Sorry about my English. What you just told me was very useful, but I’ll try to explain myself a little better. 
Thanks to “CustomMapMarker” now I can distinguish between different markers and customize them.

Comment: Imagine we have two classes of markers: Spain and Ukraine. Each one of them has its respective ahref with its class associated. Spain -> City #1 - City 2# Ukraine -> City#1 - City 2# Now I want to create an ahref, for example, in Ukraine, so when I click on it, Spain markers are hidden. And vice versa, a link in Spain that hides Ukraine markers when I click on it. I’m confused with the function of your code in “MapMarker.prototype.bind", I don’t understand how to apply the condition that hides or shows the markers there.

Comment: I see. Check [THIS](https://jsfiddle.net/9Lemwp07/16/). If need any explanations feel free to ask.

Comment: This is great Dimitri, it is almost all what I was looking for. I’m attaching here a [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/thetipico/wmnbetds/1/) now I have to create a link for each country that allows me to center the screen and only visualize the markers of the country selected. 
What would be the best solution? A hidden marker? Or maybe adding a prototype?

Comment: I made a new [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/thetipico/wmnbetds/2/), but I not sure if is the corret way. I mean, I would integrate it in your constructor and control aspects as the zoom marker on each country. I really appreciate your help

Comment: Well, on my opinion using the [google.maps.LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) class instead of hard-coded coordinates of countries is preferable. Check new methods panToSiblings() and hideInfo(). There were few more changes which I've commented out. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9Lemwp07/36/).

Comment: Awesome, Dimitri, this is exactly what I needed. The way you set out and explain the code is just spectacular. Thanks a lot for this masterclass. You have a free beer waiting for you here in Barcelona.

Comment: Too much of honor for me for such a little help :) It was my pleasure, thank you too.

Comment: I have another question about the code, how do you modify the code to make the virtual marker accept two categories? For example filtering by region de markers and show all subregions in virtual top market, the demo here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/thetipico/79erbq87/2/), like adding in "data-country" two tags for example: "spain barcelona", Thanks for your time and attention.