# Open Google Maps Info Box by Using Link

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Okay, I hope this makes sense. Below is my code for my Google Map and it's working great (not the cleanest, but it's working). How could I create a HTML link, outside of the map that would open the info box for me? For example, I want to be able to do:

```
 <a href="#map" onclick="openInfo(2)">More Info</a>
```

and that would open the info box for marker 2, which would be the Tuesday one. Hope this makes sense.

```
 <script>
 jQuery(function($) {
// Asynchronously Load the map API 
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&callback=initialize&key=APIKEY";
document.body.appendChild(script);
 });
 var gmarkers = [];
 function initialize() {
var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var mapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
};

// Display a map on the page
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
map.setTilt(45);

// Multiple Markers
var markers = [

        ['1', LAT,LONG],    
        ['2', LAT,LONG],    

];


// Info Window Content
var infoWindowContent = [

        ['<strong>Monday - 7:00pm</strong>'],       
        ['<strong>Tuesday - 6:00pm</strong>'],  
];

// Display multiple markers on a map
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

// Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: markers[i][0]
    });
    // Allow each marker to have an info window    
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));

    // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}



// Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
    this.setZoom(11);
    google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
});
var opt = { minZoom: 9, maxZoom: 12 };
map.setOptions(opt);

}
</script>
```

Comment: <a href="javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(markers[0],'click');">Open Info Window</a> I think this post will help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333679/google-maps-open-info-window-after-click-on-a-link

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I get the following error:
VM10743:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: markers is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You do have to pass it your actual marker... You are creating your markers with marker = new google.maps.Marker({... you have to store the one you want to target, and pass that to the onclick trigger funtion.

Comment: I want to be able to target any of them with the custom ID I assigned to them, so for example, If I have a marker with ID 34, then I want to be able to call markers[34] for that info window. Does that make sense? I don't want to rely on the automated 0,1,2,3 numbering for the markers.