# Google map: Open specific Info window on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I have used google map custom marker with info windows. I need to **add function to open Info window when user click on specific button**. There are multiple markers with separate contents. Here i found a solution to open a single Info window with a single button click: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18334899/6191987

I have tried with the above solution, but i don't know how to target to open each specific Info windows on button click.

Here is the code what i have tried:

```css
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .btns {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px
  }
  
  .btns a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    background: #eee;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

```html
<div class="btns">
  <a href="#" onclick="myClick(0);">Open Info Window 1</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="myClick(0);">Open Info Window 2</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="myClick(0);">Open Info Window 3</a>
</div>

<div id="map"></div>

<script>
  var map;

  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 17,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.712696, -74.005019),
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
      styles: [{
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#242f3e'
        }]
      }, {
        elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#242f3e'
        }]
      }, {
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#746855'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'administrative.locality',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#d59563'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'poi',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#d59563'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'poi.park',
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#263c3f'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'poi.park',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#6b9a76'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'road',
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#38414e'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'road',
        elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#212a37'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'road',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#9ca5b3'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'road.highway',
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#746855'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'road.highway',
        elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#1f2835'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'road.highway',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#f3d19c'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'transit',
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#2f3948'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'transit.station',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#d59563'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'water',
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#17263c'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'water',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#515c6d'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'water',
        elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#17263c'
        }]
      }]
    });

    var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
    var icons = {
      parking: {
        icon: iconBase + 'parking_lot_maps.png'
      },
      library: {
        icon: iconBase + 'library_maps.png'
      },
      info: {
        icon: iconBase + 'info-i_maps.png'
      }
    };

    var features = [{
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.712696, -74.005019),
      content: 'test content one',
      type: 'parking'
    }, {
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.712753, -74.006081),
      content: 'test content two',
      type: 'parking'
    }, {
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.713664, -74.007819),
      content: 'test content three <a href="http://www.google.com">A link to google</a>',
      type: 'library'
    }];

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: ""
    });

    // Create markers.
    features.forEach(function(feature) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: feature.position,
        content: feature.content,
        icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
        map: map
      });
      var content = "<a href='" + feature.content + "'>A link to google</a>";
      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + marker.content + '</strong></div>');

        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    });
  }
  //on click function
  function myClick(id) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[id], 'click');
  }

</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDvkk7wNQcIYXZ7S8XNG8cG-elq0QE2v3k&callback=initMap">


</script>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vishnuprasadps/3wk7q3fd/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because `markers` is not a defined variable in your code. At the top of your code, you can simply declare `markers` as an empty array, i.e.:

```
var markers = [];
```

Further down close to the bottom of your code, when you are iterating through your `features` collection, you have to push the marker object into this array, i.e.: `markers.push(marker);`. In the context of your code, it will look something like this:

```
// Create markers.
features.forEach(function(feature) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: feature.position,
    content: feature.content,
    icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
    map: map
  });
  var content = "<a href='" + feature.content + "'>A link to google</a>";
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + marker.content + '</strong></div>');

    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  // Push your marker object into your array
  markers.push(marker);
});
```

---

And that should work: see proof-of-concept below. Note: I have taken the liberty to change the inline JS callback arguments, so that you will not trigger the same marker info window for all 3 links.

```css
html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .btns {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px
  }
  
  .btns a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    background: #eee;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

```html
<div class="btns">
  <a href="#" onclick="myClick(0);">Open Info Window 1</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="myClick(1);">Open Info Window 2</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="myClick(2);">Open Info Window 3</a>
</div>

<div id="map"></div>

<script>
  var map;
  var markers = [];

  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 17,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.712696, -74.005019),
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
      styles: [{
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#242f3e'
        }]
      }, {
        elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#242f3e'
        }]
      }, {
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#746855'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'administrative.locality',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#d59563'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'poi',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#d59563'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'poi.park',
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#263c3f'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'poi.park',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#6b9a76'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'road',
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#38414e'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'road',
        elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#212a37'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'road',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#9ca5b3'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'road.highway',
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#746855'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'road.highway',
        elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#1f2835'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'road.highway',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#f3d19c'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'transit',
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#2f3948'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'transit.station',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#d59563'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'water',
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#17263c'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'water',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#515c6d'
        }]
      }, {
        featureType: 'water',
        elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
        stylers: [{
          color: '#17263c'
        }]
      }]
    });

    var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
    var icons = {
      parking: {
        icon: iconBase + 'parking_lot_maps.png'
      },
      library: {
        icon: iconBase + 'library_maps.png'
      },
      info: {
        icon: iconBase + 'info-i_maps.png'
      }
    };

    var features = [{
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.712696, -74.005019),
      content: 'test content one',
      type: 'parking'
    }, {
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.712753, -74.006081),
      content: 'test content two',
      type: 'parking'
    }, {
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.713664, -74.007819),
      content: 'test content three <a href="http://www.google.com">A link to google</a>',
      type: 'library'
    }];

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: ""
    });

    // Create markers.
    features.forEach(function(feature) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: feature.position,
        content: feature.content,
        icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
        map: map
      });
      var content = "<a href='" + feature.content + "'>A link to google</a>";
      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + marker.content + '</strong></div>');

        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });
      
      markers.push(marker);
    });
  }
  //on click function
  function myClick(id) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[id], 'click');
  }

</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDvkk7wNQcIYXZ7S8XNG8cG-elq0QE2v3k&callback=initMap">


</script>
```

---

Additional notes:

- **Do not use inline JS**. You can simply iterate through your links and bind event listeners to them using [`.addEventListener('click', function() {...})`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- If you have an arbitrary number of features, it helps that you get the length of this collection and generate the links dynamically

Comment: Wow..! Really Great Terry.. It is working well. Also a special Thanks for the exact explanation. Happy coding :)