# Using buttons to show correlating location map markers on a map

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm just starting out with javascript and am working with a google maps api. I want to use buttons to show locations on the map. I have different castles and when each are clicked i want the map marker correlating to the castle to pop up. I'm unsure the best way to do this with javascript. Any help is appreciated! I have all the locations of the castles in an array at the moment and have some javascript although it isnt showing anything.

```
for (i = 0; i < castles.length; i++ ) {
  var addMarker = ("The lat is " + castles[i][1]+" and the long is "+ castles[i][2]);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: castles[1], lng: castles[2]},
    map: map
  });
}
```

Comment: Not a lot of information here to work with but try: `position: {lat: castles[i][1], lng: castles[i][2]},`

Answer (score 1):

OK, so it sounds like you have an array of castle objects but not an array of markers, so let's fix that first. (Note that in your example you didn't access the right element in the array `[i]` for the lat/lng.)

```
const markers = [];

for (let i = 0; i < castles.length; i++ ) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: { lat: castles[i][1], lng: castles[i][2] },
    map: map
  });
  markers.push(marker);
}
```

I've declared a new array to keep all the markers and push each created marker into it on each iteration.

To add these to the map just iterate over the markers array and use `setMap`:

```
markers.forEach((marker) => marker.setMap(map));
```

But you also want an infowindow to appear when you click on any of the markers, so let's go back and amend that loop:

```
const markers = [];

for (let i = 0; i < castles.length; i++ ) {

  // Cache the lat and lng coords
  const lat = castles[i][1];
  const lng = castles[i][2];

  // Create a new infowindow
  const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({

    // Using your content we can create a template literal string
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals
    content: `The lat is ${lat} and the long is ${lng}`
  });

  const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: { lat, lng },
    map: map
  });

  // And we add a listener to the marker so that
  // it opens the infowindow when it is clicked
  marker.addListener('click', () => {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  markers.push(marker);
}
```

Comment: hi thank you so much! but what i want to happen is when <button type="button" class="castle-styles windsorcastle">Windsor Castle</button>  is clicked then the marker for windsor castle pops us

Comment: Looks like you can trigger a specific marker to reveal its infowindow by calling a click event on it [`google.maps.event.trigger(markers[id], 'click')`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46906666/1377002).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
position: {lat: castles[i][1], lng: castles[i][2]}
```