# How to open specific info window on google map from link when markers are in function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I open a specific marker using a link when all my Google Map markers are created from inside a function?

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-id="1" class='maplabels'>Open This Info Window</a>
```

I have tried the solution here but it doesn't work when markers are created inside a function. [Google Maps, open info window after click on a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333679/google-maps-open-info-window-after-click-on-a-link)

Here's my Javascript that produces the map markers inside a function:

```
var map = null;
var markers = [];

function addMarker(info, icon) {
  var location = {lat: info.lat, lng: info.lng};
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    icon: 'map/images/pin-icon-' + icon + '.png',
    map: map
  });

  var content = '<h3>' +  info.name + '</h3>';
  content += info.address + '<br>';
  content += info.phone;

  clickaction = "click";

   //check if mobile
   if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
     clickaction = "click";
   } else { 
     clickaction = "mouseover";
   }

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, clickaction, function() {
    if (infowindow) {
      infowindow.close();
    }

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
    infowindow.setContent(content);
    infowindow.open(map,marker);

  });

 markers.push(marker);

}


function addMarkerPerCategory(category) {
  deleteMarkers();

  if (category == 'ALL') {
    for (var i = 0; i < mapPinInfo.restaurants.length; i++) {
      addMarker(mapPinInfo.restaurants[i], 1);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < mapPinInfo.transportation.length; i++) {
      addMarker(mapPinInfo.transportation[i], 1);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < mapPinInfo.shopping.length; i++) {
      addMarker(mapPinInfo.shopping[i], 1);
    }
  } else if (category == 'RESTAURANTS') {
    for (var i = 0; i < mapPinInfo.restaurants.length; i++) {
      addMarker(mapPinInfo.restaurants[i], 1);
    }
  } else if (category == 'TRANSPORTATION') {
    for (var i = 0; i < mapPinInfo.transportation.length; i++) {
      addMarker(mapPinInfo.transportation[i], 1);
    }
  } else if (category == 'SHOPPING') {
    for (var i = 0; i < mapPinInfo.shopping.length; i++) {
      addMarker(mapPinInfo.shopping[i], 1);
    }
  } 
}

function initMap() {
  addMarkerPerCategory('ALL');
}
```

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't work when the marker is created in a function.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem (or at least how you tried to implement that answer in your code that didn't work, where you expected it to work, there really shouldn't be any difference in the solution when you build the marker in a function).

Answer (score 2):

There are three things you need to do based on codes you have now.

1. You need a global infowindow just as the map and markers
2. Save you assets information to marker including id, name and so on
3. You need a clickOpenInfowindow function bind to a onclick event, which pass in id which can find target marker in markers array and then refresh the infowindow

```

```
var map = null;
var markers = [];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()

function clickOpenInfowindow (id) {
  // find the marker by id
  var marker = markers.find ( m => m.id === id)
  if (marker) {
      var content = '<h3>' +  marker.name + '</h3>';
      content += marker.address + '<br>';
      content += maker.phone;

      var clickaction = "click";

      //check if mobile
      if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera 
      Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        clickaction = "click";
     } else { 
       clickaction = "mouseover";
     }

    infowindow.setContent(content);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  }
}

function addMarker(info, icon) {
  var location = {lat: info.lat, lng: info.lng};
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    icon: 'map/images/pin-icon-' + icon + '.png',
    map: map
  });

  // save info content to marker
  marker.id = info.id
  marker.name = info.name
  marker.addree = info.address
  marker.phone = info.phone

  var content = '<h3>' +  info.name + '</h3>';
  content += info.address + '<br>';
  content += info.phone;

  clickaction = "click";

   //check if mobile
   if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera 
     Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
     clickaction = "click";
   } else { 
     clickaction = "mouseover";
   }

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, clickaction, function() {
    infowindow.setContent(content);
    infowindow.open(map,marker);

  });

 markers.push(marker);

}


function addMarkerPerCategory(category) {
  deleteMarkers();

  if (category == 'ALL') {
    for (var i = 0; i < mapPinInfo.restaurants.length; i++) {
      addMarker(mapPinInfo.restaurants[i], 1);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < mapPinInfo.transportation.length; i++) {
      addMarker(mapPinInfo.transportation[i], 1);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < mapPinInfo.shopping.length; i++) {
      addMarker(mapPinInfo.shopping[i], 1);
    }
  } else if (category == 'RESTAURANTS') {
    for (var i = 0; i < mapPinInfo.restaurants.length; i++) {
      addMarker(mapPinInfo.restaurants[i], 1);
    }
  } else if (category == 'TRANSPORTATION') {
    for (var i = 0; i < mapPinInfo.transportation.length; i++) {
      addMarker(mapPinInfo.transportation[i], 1);
    }
  } else if (category == 'SHOPPING') {
    for (var i = 0; i < mapPinInfo.shopping.length; i++) {
      addMarker(mapPinInfo.shopping[i], 1);
    }
  } 
}

function initMap() {
  addMarkerPerCategory('ALL');
}
```

Comment: Thank you this has helped me come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this function enabled me to catch any item in my map object.

I hope it helps someone:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class='maplabels' onClick="clickOpenInfowindow(1,'cat1');">Open Marker Info Window</a>
```

...

```
var infowindow = null;
var mapPinInfo = {
  cat1: [
    {name: 'Lorem Ipsum', address: 'Lorem Ipsum', lat: 55.5555, lng: -55.5555},
  ],
  cat2: [
    {name: 'Lorem Ipsum', address: 'Lorem Ipsum', lat: 55.5555, lng: -55.5555},
  ],
  cat3: [
    {name: 'Lorem Ipsum', address: 'Lorem Ipsum', lat: 55.5555, lng: -55.5555},
  ]
};
```

....

```
function clickOpenInfowindow (id,cat) {
  // find the marker by id and show category
  addMarkerPerCategory(cat); //function that opens the category filter
  var marker = markers[id];
  var category = cat.toLowerCase();
  var name = mapPinInfo[category][id].name;
  var address = mapPinInfo[category][id].address;
  if (marker) {
      var content = '<h3>' +  name + '</h3>';
      content += address + '<br>';

      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      infowindow.setContent(content);
      setTimeout(function(){ 
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }, 200);

  }
}
```